# Auto-completion for citation in Kile using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, kile, auto-completion

Currently in Kile you can get citation auto-completion when using BibTeX. You just add `\bibliography{file}` and Kile knows from this where the bib file is and what is in it.

However biblatex does not use this command. Instead you must use `\addbibresource{file.bib}` in the preamble. Kile dos not recognise this, even though it specifies the path to the bib file in the same way, and therefore I can't get citation autocompletion.

Is there a way to get Kile to recognise the `\addbibresource{}` command as providing the path to the bibliography?

Edited: as @Psirus says there is backwards compatibility in biblatex. `\bibliography{file}` can be used for the time being without problem.

Comment: From the biblatex manual: `\bibliography: The legacy command for adding bibliographic resources, supported for backwards compatibility. Like \addbibresource, this command is only available in the preamble and adds resources to the default resource list. ... This command is deprecated. Please consider using \addbibresource instead.` You could just replace `\addbibresource` with `\bibliography` for now, maybe Kile adds biblatex support before biblatex drops `\bibliography`.

Comment: Indeed, `\bibliography` works. There is no need to change commands each time. Thanks!

Comment: "`\bibliography` can be used for the time being..." is crucial here, the more futureproof version (regarding your document, not necessarily Kile) is zeroth answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple yet workable solution is to enclose the `\bibliography` command somewhere it is never executed. Here are various methods:

```
\iffalse
    \bibliography{test1.bib}
    \bibliography{test2.bib}
\fi
\newcommand\NEVERRUNME{
    \bibliography{test1.bib}
    \bibliography{test2.bib}
}
```

They provide what Kile reads but never parses it...
It does not do what Kile is supposed to do, however, you cheat Kile in to thinking the correct thing.

Answer (score 1):

I learned by accident that kile now supports this by default for biblatex (with just `\addbibresource{citations.bib}`) when used in conjunction with their projects feature.

You need to create a new project in kile and add all the relevant `.tex` files along with all the relevant `.bib` files to the project after which auto-completion works inside the `\cite` command